# Start external activity in previous state on android

Tags: android, start-activity

I am trying to start **com.google.android.talk** application with previous state from other activity. But always it start from first page (list of buddies)

```
Intent launchIntent =getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.talk");
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: you could use SingleInstance  in your Menifest, so there will be only one instance for this activity and if it already started it will be reordered from stack...

Comment: that or onsavedinstnacestate onrestoreinstnacestate....also an option for you...override onStop and onResume and load all your information back